# Error 500 (Run From Package Initialization failed) while doing web deploy with Azure Piplines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to publish a Blazor net core app using Azure Pipelines, but I constantly get a 500 error on the Web Deployment stage.

Once the pipeline runs I check through Kudu console and the only two files on the server are an empty `web.config` and `FAILED TO INITIALIZE RUN FROM PACKAGE.txt` with `Run From Package Initialization failed.` inside.

Below is the YAML of the pipeline.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.Config

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/TPL/Server/TPL.Server.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: tpl'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '**hidden**'
    WebAppName: tpl
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: TPL
    SlotName: test
    packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and recreating the slot fixed this. I previously had old way CI (from portal's deployment center menu) and my hunch is that didn't get disconnected properly or something like that didn't get cleaned up.